# My post request would stop after ten hours

Tags: python, post, process, request

When I test the high availability switch, every minute I send a post request to add the host.

```
import requests
import json
import time
from itertools import product
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

url = 'https://ip/api/hosts'
access_token = 'token'
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
num = 1
for i,j in product(range(256),range(256)):
    ip = "xx.xx.{0}.{1}".format(i,j)
    postData = {'departmentId': 3, 'hostIp': ip, 'hostname': "{0}_times".format(num) }
    headers = {'AccessToken': access_token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    try:
        r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(postData), verify=False)
        print r
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        r.status_code = "Connection refused"
        print r.status_code
    time.sleep(60)
    num += 1
```

I execute this script with this command:`python -u request_Add_Host.py >> ./log.txt &`

The contents of the log are like this：

```
...
<Response [201]>
...
Connection refused
...
```

The log stopped at around 600 lines. After replacing `time.sleep(60)` with `time.sleep(30)`, it was about 1,300 lines.

- Through the command `tcpdump dst host <ip>`, I can't catch any
  packets.
- Through the command `ps aux | grep <scripts name>`, I can see the progress of the script with state S.
- I can manually add host on the web or execute the script again to add. Both could be successful.

Comment: Maybe the server is blocking your from any further requests ?

Comment: I execute tcpdump where the script was executed and can't catch the packets from the client. @ZdaR

Comment: @yxs: Try adding [a timeout](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) to `requests.post()`. It might help you figure out if your script is stalling or just waiting.

Answer (score 0):

> The log stopped at around 600 lines.

So, assuming that the requests took a negligible amount of time, it ran for ten hours (600 minutes).

> After replacing `time.sleep(60)` with `time.sleep(30)`, it was about 1,300 lines.

Also ten hours.

All signs point ot this being something time-related. Perhaps the access token you're using expires after ten hours?

Comment: When the script stopped after ten hours, I re-execute the script , can still be successful. At this point, the token didn't change.